# C++ Same Name Different Type

Tags: c++, struct, unions, anonymous-types, bit-fields

I have an anonymous `union` which contain a `uint8_t` and a bit field `struct`.

```
union
{
  struct
  {
    uint8_t ID : 1;
    uint8_t C : 4;
    uint8_t RM : 1;
    uint8_t SWRST : 1;
    uint8_t STS : 1;
  } ControlByte1;
  uint8_t ControlByte1;
};
```

As you can see both the `uint8_t` and `struct` instances are called `ControlByte1`. What I'm trying to do is to have `ControlByte1` be a `uint8_t` while being able to access its bits with `ControlByte1.ID`, `ControlByte1.C`, `ControlByte1.RM`, `ControlByte1.SWRTS` and `ControlByte1.STS`. As expected, when I write `ControlByte1 = ...;`, `... = ControlByte1;` or `function(ControlByte1);`, the compilator has no way of knowing if I mean `ControlByte1` as a `uint8_t` or `struct`. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Edit 1:

I would just like them to have the same name because ControlByte1 is a one byte I2C control byte which contain ID, C, RM, SWRST and STS fields. I want to be able to access ControlByte1 as a byte and also access it's fields individually.

Edit 2:

I may have found a way by overloading the implicit type casting operator.

```
struct
{
  uint8_t ID : 1;
  uint8_t C : 4;
  uint8_t RM : 1;
  uint8_t SWRST : 1;
  uint8_t STS : 1;
  operator uint8_t*() {return (uint8_t *)this;}
  operator uint8_t() {return *(uint8_t *)this;}
} ControlByte1;
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing the overloading correctly but it does compile, I haven't tried running my code yet.

```
uint8_t var1 = ControlByte1; // Compile
uint8_t *ptr1 = ControlByte1; // Compile
uint8_t *ptr2 = &ControlByte1; // Does not compile!!!
var1 = ControlByte1; // Compile
ptr1 = ControlByte1; // Compile
ptr2 = &ControlByte1; // Does not compile!!!
```

I'm guessing that `&ControlByte1` does not compile because I need to overload the `&` operator too? There is no need to overload assignment operator because I do not assign anything directly to `ControlByte1`.

Edit 3:

This make more sense.

```
struct
{
  uint8_t ID : 1;
  uint8_t C : 4;
  uint8_t RM : 1;
  uint8_t SWRST : 1;
  uint8_t STS : 1;
  // For implicit casting to uint8_t
  operator uint8_t() const
  {
    return(*(uint8_t *)this);
  }
  // For implicit casting to uint8_t *
  uint8_t * operator &() const
  {
    return((uint8_t *)this);
  }
} ControlByte1;
```

Comment: Why can't the names be different? What am I missing?

Comment: There are ways you can fake it with a custom type having an implicit conversion operator, but that might be a bit much for this case. The simpler approach of renaming the union something like `ControlByte1Fields` would probably be better and less confusing.

Comment: In this case, the best and simplest solution, both for implementing it and using the `union` is simply use 2 names.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you try to solve? Why do you need this union? Why does the members of the union need to have the same name?

Comment: @Bathsheba They can be different. I would just like them to be the same because ControlByte1 is a one byte hardware register which contain ID, C, RM, SWRST and STS fields. I want to be able to access ControlByte1 as a byte and also access it's fields.

Comment: @A.Lacasse A custom type with a pointer to the register could do this but with some caveats. For example, implicit conversion only happens in a context where conversion is required.

Comment: @cdhowie The register is not a CPU register. It's a touch controller register.

Comment: @A.Lacasse I didn't say it was a CPU register!? ... You can't have a pointer to a CPU register anyway, so I'm not sure what in my comment made you think I meant a CPU register.

Comment: @cdhowie My bad! I though you were saying a pointer to the register address

Comment: @A.Lacasse I am. The hardware register's address. :)

Comment: @cdhowie Actually I said hardware register to make things more understandable but in reality it's the control byte of an I2C transmission. So there is no register address. I should have said this right away sorry about this confusion.

Comment: @A.Lacasse Either way, surely it's a value we can take a pointer/reference to. A wrapper class around such a pointer/reference could potentially achieve your goal with some caveats, though I'm not sure usage would actually wind up being simpler.

Comment: Note that (though your compiler may allow it) even if you use different names [it's undefined behavior to read from a union member other than the last one written](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)

Comment: @cdhowie I think I'll end up using different names sounds much simpler and elegant. Also you had me thinking when you said  "You can't have a pointer to a CPU register anyway". I totally agree with you but let's say I have `register uint8_t var;` wouldn't `uint8_t *ptr = &var;` be a pointer to a register? I'm expecting the compiler to complain about this.

Comment: @A.Lacasse The `register` keyword is deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17. It used to be a hint in C that a variable should be put in a register. Modern compilers can figure this out on their own and ignore the keyword. Taking a pointer to a `register` variable will cause g++ to emit a warning, but otherwise there are no ill effects -- other than that taking a pointer may prevent the compiler from using a register to store the value. (It also might not if the pointer is not passed to an opaque function.)

Comment: If it is a hardware register, you probably should qualify it `volatile uint8_t* ControlByte1 = reinterpret_cast<volatile uint8_t*>(0x6000600060006000);`.  That's one of the three use cases of `volatile` that I've used (hardware register, setjmp/longjmp, global `int` used with signal handler).